# Firebase append complete list at a time

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, append

I have browsed net and came through many ways of appending whole list in firebase database by iterating on `snapshot.getchildren()`. 
Basically following function is what I am talking about.

```
private void func (DatabaseReference ref, DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot childSnapShot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

    ref.child(childSnapShot.getKey()).setValueAsync(childSnapShot.getValue());
    //or
    ref.push().setValueAsync(childSnapShot.getValue());
    }
}
```

But I want to know a way such that I can append whole snapshot children data at one go without any iteration.

`ref.push().setValueAsync(snapshot.value());`

The above statement appends data at one go but creates an extra key at parent layer. 
whereas 
`ref.setValueAsync(snapshot.value());` overwrites entire firebase instead of append.

Is it possible to append whole list at a single go ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can get the `snapshot` object, cast it to a `HashMap` object and then directly set it on the reference without iterating like this:

```
private void func (DatabaseReference ref, DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    val map : HashMap<String, Any> = snapshot.getValue() as HashMap<String, Any>;
    ref.setValue(map);
}
```

Comment: Hi what is p0 ? is it snapshot? Secondly isn't  ref.setValue(map); same as ref.setValueAsync(snapshot.value()); which will overwrite complete firebase instead appending.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Should be `snapshot` not p0. Yes is a `snapshot` object. Yes it will set the value but you'll don't need to loop throught the entire `DataSnapshot` object anymore. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: Actually what I wanted is **appending** this snapshot's value to current firebase's existing data. Setting **overwrites** firebase with just this snapshot's value and I end up loosing existing firebase data.

Comment: I understand. In this case you should use `updateChildren()` function and not `setValue()`. Does it work this way?